# /execute command not working

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to use this command in Minecraft Bedrock 19.81

```
execute at @e[type=wither_skeleton] run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ wool 3
```

I set the command block to repeat and needs Redstone.

However, it's not working, even though I copied it down from the tutorial perfectly.

Comment: have you tried setting the commandblock to always active? or to power it with redstone?

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell you what's wrong with your command.

First of all you wrote `execute at` and it's wrong, you have to use `execute as` . It's a basic syntax, so no need to explain why.

After that you wrote `execute as @e[type=wither_skeleton] at @e[type=wither_skeleton]`, there's no need to make this lengthy, you should simply write:

```
/execute as @e[type=wither_skeleton] at @s
```

By writing `at @s` we define the system that assigns the entity we are talking about as `@s`.

So the whole command is:

```
/execute as @e[type=wither_skeleton] at @s run setblock ~~-1~ wool 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
execute as @e[type=wither_skeleton] at @e[type=wither_skeleton] run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ wool 3
```

Comment: Maybe add an explanation and not just a line of code to let OP learn how this works?